# Android-Show overdraw areas option not working

Tags: android, performance, gpu

I want to use show overdraw areas option in Android to check my own app whether there exists overdrawing. I followed this guide : https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-overdraw.html#VisualizingOverdraw , but I found that the option works fine with Android system and most of apps on my phone except my own one. I can't use the tool to check any view/viewGroup on my app. I googled a lot but got nothing. I just wonder why, and how can I use the tool to check overdrawing situation.

BTW, Profile GPU Rendering-On screen as bars doesn't work either.

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

Delete this from manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```